# gnu screen: rename without erasing previous name?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

On my workflow i always have a bunch of custom named screens.

I use  <kbd>screen modified, e.g. Ctrl-a</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>: to get to the rename mode. It will start with the previous name, and the cursor at the end. I then must press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase it all, and then type the name.

Most of the time I am on automatic brainless mode and forget to erase the old name, ending up with something like "bashNewname".

I could edit my screenrc to set the default name to "" instead, but i use tons of systems that lack my screenrc. So if there were a command i do not know about instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and that is available on all standard gnu screen installs, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a screen window's title with escape sequences (from the [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Naming-Windows)):

> To change the name after the window has been created you can use the **title-string escape-sequence (`<ESC> k name <ESC> \`)** and the title command (C-a A).

For quick-and-dirty one-offs, simply `echo -e` your destired title in that window's shell (`\033` is equivalent to `<ESC>`, and `-e` interprets escape sequences):

```
$ echo -e '\033k NewTitle\033\'
```

... though `printf` might be faster to type and more portable:

```
$ printf '\033k NewTitle\033\'
```

Either of these commands should result in `NewTitle` appearing as the title of your current window.

It won't be difficult to automate that with a shell alias or function, though some kind of keyboard macro might be more useful if you're frequently using this on remote systems (eg through ssh) that won't share your shell rc files.

Comment: thanks. I have that for some cases. But nowadays i mostly set the titles by hand (e.g. code, test, run)

Comment: @gcb was thinking of something like [sxhkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sxhkd) for macros: set something like `ctrl+shift+f1` to send the `printf '\033k[space]`, and `ctrl+shift+f2` to send the `\033\'`.  set it up on your local X and then `ctrl+shift+f1, NewTitle, ctrl+shift+f2, [enter]` gets your new window title in screen, no remote config necessary.